# How can I update a child object in an Array in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following problem, I edit patient info and want to update this patients info. What is the best way to do this?

```
var department = mongoose.model('department', {
  departmentName: String,
  rooms: [{
    roomNumber: String,
    width: Number,
    height: Number,
    posX: Number,
    posY: Number,
    sanitary: Boolean,
    childcareArea: Boolean,
    lounge: Boolean,
    patient: {
      patientnr: Number,
      firstname: String,
      lastname: String,
      reasonOfHospitalization: String,
      dateOfHospitalization: String,
      expectedDateOfDischarge: String,
      vegetarian: Boolean,
      needsHelp: Boolean,
      comments: String,
      department: String,
      roomNumber: String,
      nextTreatment: {
        type: String,
        shortDescription: String,
        timestamp: String
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

I will probably need something like this...

```
app.post('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {
  department.update({..})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something along the lines of

```
app.post('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {

    //first, find the document
    department.findById(req.params.id, function(err, dept){

        //make changes accordingly
        dept.patient.firstname = 'Changed'

        dept.save(function(err){
            res.send ('Saved');
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I see you are using angular js also so you can just pass the elements that you want to update .

so your req.body can contain variables you want to update .
Remember its $set for update of object and $push for update of array

Now

```
   app.post('/api/departments/patients/:id', function(req, res) {
  department.findByIdAndUpdate({id : req.params.id}, 
     {
      $push:
        {  
        rooms.roomnumber: req.body.departmentName 
        }}, {new : true}), function(err,doc){
       console.log(doc);
     })
});
```